# IE10 and 11 quirk on SVG use and linearGradients

Tags: html, css, svg

I am creating an SVG sprite so that it can be reused multiple times throughout the site. In order to use the sprite, I am simply using `<use>` so that the symbol will be embedded in shadow DOM:

```
<!-- Icon -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
        <stop stop-color="steelblue" stop-opacity="1" offset="0%" />
        <stop stop-color="steelblue" stop-opacity="0" offset="100%" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#svg-icon-grad" />
</svg>

<!-- Sprite -->
<svg style="display: none">
  <symbol id="svg-icon-grad" viewBox="0 0 250 100">
    <rect fill="url(#grad1)" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

The issue is that when I attempt to use a `<linearGradient>` as the fill attribute, it breaks in IE10 and 11. Strangely enough, it works perfectly fine in IE9, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera.

I know that if I avoid using `<use>` and instead embed the contents of the `<symbol>` directly, the linear gradient will work in IE10 and 11. However, I will want to avoid this since I prefer the sprites be stored in a separate file for easy maintenance.

Here is the code snippet:

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Icon with fill -->
This is an icon with a fill, works in all browsers
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use xlink:href="#svg-icon-fill" />
</svg>

<hr />

<!-- Icon with linear gradient -->
This is an icon with linear gradient, works in all browsers but breaks in IE10 and IE11 only (works in IE9)
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
        <stop stop-color="steelblue" stop-opacity="1" offset="0%" />
        <stop stop-color="steelblue" stop-opacity="0" offset="100%" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
        <stop stop-color="red" stop-opacity="1" offset="0%" />
        <stop stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0" offset="100%" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#svg-icon-grad" />
</svg>

<!-- Sprite -->
<svg style="display: none">
  <symbol id="svg-icon-fill" viewBox="0 0 250 100">
    <rect fill="steelblue" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
    <circle fill="red" cx="200" cy="50" r="50" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="svg-icon-grad" viewBox="0 0 250 100">
    <rect fill="url(#grad1)" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
    <circle fill="url(#grad2)" cx="200" cy="50" r="50" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

As attached is the screenshot in various browsers:

### IE9 (works):

[image: IE9]

### IE10 (*broken*):

[image: IE10]

### IE11 (*broken*):

[image: IE11]

### Chrome (works):

[image: Google Chrome]

### Firefox (works):

[image: Mozilla Firefox]

### Safari (works):

[image: OS X Safari]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `display: none` to hide the "sprite", use `width="0"` and `height="0"`.

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Icon with fill -->
This is an icon with a fill, works in all browsers
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use xlink:href="#svg-icon-fill" />
</svg>

<hr />

<!-- Icon with linear gradient -->
This is an icon with linear gradient, works in all browsers but breaks in IE10 and IE11 only (works in IE9)
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
        <stop stop-color="steelblue" stop-opacity="1" offset="0%" />
        <stop stop-color="steelblue" stop-opacity="0" offset="100%" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
        <stop stop-color="red" stop-opacity="1" offset="0%" />
        <stop stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0" offset="100%" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#svg-icon-grad" />
</svg>

<!-- Sprite -->
<svg style="width:0; height:0; visibility:hidden;">
  <symbol id="svg-icon-fill" viewBox="0 0 250 100">
    <rect fill="steelblue" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
    <circle fill="red" cx="200" cy="50" r="50" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="svg-icon-grad" viewBox="0 0 250 100">
    <rect fill="url(#grad1)" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
    <circle fill="url(#grad2)" cx="200" cy="50" r="50" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked beautifully! Is there an explanation behind this? I just found an identical solution on GitHub, pretty cool ;) https://github.com/emilbjorklund/svg-weirdness/issues/12

Comment: In IE10 and IE11, the  `<linearGradient>` is erroneously inheriting the `display: none` from the sprite. Various browsers have different bugs related to using `display: none` in symbol/defs SVGs.  It's always a good idea to avoid using that method to hide the SVG.